# Working with fragments - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I received a null pointer exception error on my activity that holds various fragments. In that activity a list of users would be populated to the current users through parse based around various criteria like gender, minimum age, etc.

Below is the logcat message I unexpectedly received when launching my application.

```
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 4974
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1$1.done(Fragment1.java:108)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:1)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:888)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-15 17:42:28.863: E/AndroidRuntime(4974):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the activity code that holds the fragment where the error occured

```
 public class usermatch extends FragmentActivity {
        private PageAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
            initialisePaging();

        }

        private void initialisePaging() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
            mPagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mood, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Below is the fragment activity code where I believe the error is triggered

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");


    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (container == null){
            return null;
        }
        setConversationsList();

        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, 
                container,false);

}
private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    //  query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());

                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
    }
    }
```

Update
Logcat message

```
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1340
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1$1.done(Fragment1.java:108)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:1)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:888)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-15 19:23:27.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 108

```
        usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
```

Updated Activity Code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
    //  query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());

                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am a bit confused, and even with research done, I have difficulty finding, and solving the issues.
Kindly advise,
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is on line 108 of fragment1.java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the views you are finding in `setConversationsList()` are from the fragment's layout (`R.layout.fragment1_layout`), then you must inflate the layout first:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

    setConversationsList();

    return view;
}
```

Note that using `getActivity` before `onActivityCreated` is perfectly normal as it's already available since `onAttach`. However if the views you are looking for, belong to the activity's layout, then you should be finding them in `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have unfortunately experienced another nullpointer exception while trying to run the application. I am not sure if this is a step forward or not, but wouldn't you mind taking a look at it. I have updated the code under my initial post

Comment: @user3907211 please mark the 108th line in your updated Fragment1 code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.     usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
is line 108

Comment: @user3907211 obviously the ListView with id `R.id.usersListView` is not found. Make sure it's inside of your activity's or the fragment's layout.

Comment: Yeah that's true. This has resolve my issue and solved my case.

Answer (score 2):

Again, you are calling `getActivity()` prior to `onActivityCreated()`, and therefore `getActivity()` returns null.

`onCreateView()` is called prior to `onActivityCreated()`. `onActivityCreated()` is `Called when the activity's onCreate() method has returned.` That means that when `onCreateView()` is called, the fragment's `getActivitiy()` method would return null.

In `onCreateView()` you call `setConversationsList()` which access `getActivity()` in multiple places. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to move things around, but I am not sure where I should call it to not run into other errors.

Comment: @user3907211 Can you move `setConversationsList()` to `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: @user3907211 Why don't you try adding `onActivityCreated` to your fragment?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added onActivityCreated to the fragment, but unfortunately this has resulted in another nullpointer exception code. I have updated the updated code in my initial post, if you could kindly look into it that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: @user3907211 In which line do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In line 108 -     usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

Comment: @user3907211 Is `usersListView` null?

Comment: The list has items into but it was a small typo, where i reference the wrong layout list. My issue have been resolved, and I think you much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check if `List<ParseUser> userList` is null or not before iterating.